# Excel: Type function showing 2 (text), Need to change it to number? format not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am getting a report and trying to do a `=vlookup()`. I have found the issue being that one of the reports brings back some values as a Type(2), and the `VLOOKUP` is showing `#N/A` as the other one is a Type(1).

I have tried to format cells to numbers but that does not work. The only thing that works is manually going into the cell, typing an extra character at the end and then deleting it and then clicking out of the cell.

Is there a way to do this automatically or something?

Comment: try text2columns, fixed width, finish.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow force the change in the primary cells? It is only doing it to some of them and it would cause a headache to add a new column

Comment: Do the cells that contain these *pseudo-numbers* have formulas in them or constants in them??

Comment: They’re number, letters, special characters. No formulas

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a column of values from **C2** through **C100** that have text values that **look like** numbers, but are not.
First format the cells to `General`.  Then place ***1*** a cell; copy that cell; PasteSpecialMultiply over the the cells in column **C**.

Just changing the format of the **C** cells will not change their values.